# How do you handle software upgrades like SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2005

I'm only asking this because I'm finding as I get older, it becomes a much more frustrating part of my job.

How do you handle new versions of software, particularly software that coders and DBAs use on a regular basis?  It seems that just when I've fleshed out SQL2005, SQL2008 will have come and gone and SQL2010 will be here.  I've missed a whole iteration and this isn't endemic to coders and DBAs.

I'm never for upgrading just for the sake of upgrading so unless there is compelling functionality there, I tend to let it go.  Somehow though, with software releases becoming more frequent, I can't help but feel that this is the wrong approach.

**Edited to add:**
I guess part of what I'm saying is that the release of newer versions hardly leaves enough time to become an expert in the previous version.

Comment: damn, i was just writing an answer to your "what did you learn about your language today" question when it got deleted :/ silly people, it's cool question

Comment: Yeah.  I think my participation here is going to dwindle down a bit.  It's not the first question that I've asked that's been voted down and people wanted it closed.  Whatever.  Sorry for deleting it but I'm frustrated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rarely do these upgrades require a lot to be relearned.  Actually, I would almost argue, that the amount to relearn is proportional to the amount of time between releases.  So SQL Server 2000 to 2005 was 5 years, and quite a lot changed.  2005 to 2008, not much changed.  2008 to 2010, I'm guessing that there won't be a lot to learn.  I think the trick is to keep on top of things.  Because if you fall a few versions back, it can be a nightmare to catch up on things.  Even if you just play around with it and don't use it in live projects, you are probably further ahead than a lot of people.

Comment: Seems like it's every other release with most MS stuff - not counting the R2 stuff they're doing now. But, yeah, falling more than 2 major releases behind can be a killer.

Answer (score 1):

For server based software that needs to be stable, hitting "every release" isn't necessary a good thing. The only benefits you get from a new version are the new features (which if you don't need them, are not a concern) and finding all the incompatibilities *now* that might bite in the *next* release as well (on top of those included in the next release).

For this reason, we still support SQL 2000 on our primary product. We have ported and tested it against 2005 and 2008... but we are *not* using those new features. Too many clients are still running 2000. We are finally looking to cut support for 2000 when 2010 comes out, as 10 years seems a reasonable period, so our newest (not generally released, but in use with some clients) version uses some 2005 features.

As far as our development environment goes, we did move to 2005 and 2008 about a year after each release (when the first service packs were out). That is because the *client* isn't on the treadmill there, so we are more aggressive. The features in 2005 and 2008 were also compelling (I don't use Linq to SQL, but I *love* Linq to Objects ). We also do a lot of prototyping on newer versions of software, and keep our internal projects on newer software to keep up with the technologies features for planning and learning.

As far as becoming an expert, I think that with the scope of the technologies in question, nobody is an expert in the entire product. If you know all about the query optimization engine and how to wring the last bit of performance out of it, you are less likely to have spent a lot of time on the replication engine. Personally, I think you should sample everything, but at the end of the day you have to get to work: and your work will rarely require you to be an expert at everything. Just knowing that the features are there are enough so that the day you need them... you can quickly acquire a new skill and move on.